# What is a require("http") in node.js

Tags: node.js

While learning node.js I read that

We use require directive to load http module and store returned HTTP
 instance into http variable as follows −

```
var http = require("http");
```

I want to know what does `http` module means ?

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to think of modules is to think of them as libraries. They add additional functionality into your application based on which modules you decide to import and use.

The http module is most beneficial in nodejs when you need to make a request over the hyper text transfer protocol. For example, if you want to send a `post` request or `get` request to a specific url, you can't use something like `ajax` which only works in the frontend. You will need to use the `http module` in order to do something like this (or use a related module but http is one of the more common ones).

The http module also has additional functionality such as creating a server or managing sockets. I recommend looking at the api for specific details- but if you are doing anything related to sending data over http: the http module is definitely worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to explain will be to tell you that the http module enables you to make requests to servers. If you however will like to get a proper understanding of how the node http module works then I will refer you to the documentation here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

The documentation might seem be a bit heavy if you do not like to read but it does go very deep which is why I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish the module pattern like ‘Anonymous closure’,  'Global import in JQuery Module',  'CommonJS required', AMD, UMD etc. Mostly, these module patterns mainly returns the reference to the object. So in CommonJS 'required' is for using the module where as 'export' is used for exporting the module. So when we say var http = require("http"); Here, require("http") invokes javascript module loader to check for existence of mode with name "http". if he finds it it returns the reference to that module and we store it in variable http. There is good article, [Writing Modular JavaScript With AMD, CommonJS & ES Harmony](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) which explains different module loaders in javascript and CommonJS require/export